# File upload code not working after AWSSDK update from v2.3 to v3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

Last Month we updated the Amazon AWSSDK nuget package from version 2.3 to 3.1. After that none of the files are being uploaded to server but I am not getting any errors. We I try to access the location I either get 404 or files with 0bytes

Here's the code. What am I missing?

```
            var keyName = Globals.configSettings.AmazonS3ApiKey;
            var apiId = Globals.configSettings.AmazonS3ApiId;
            var fileName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ChangedFileName) ? ChangedFileName : fileUploadDownloadable.FileName;

            using (var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(apiId, keyName, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)))
            {
                var bucketName = Globals.configSettings.AmazonS3ApiBucketName;
                var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = "images/downloads/" + fileName,
                    InputStream = fileUploadDownloadable.PostedFile.InputStream
                };

                fileTransferUtility.Upload(request);
            }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason when I changed my code to this, it started working.. I have no idea why

```
            var keyName = Globals.configSettings.AmazonS3ApiKey;
            var apiId = Globals.configSettings.AmazonS3ApiId;
            var fileName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ChangedFileName) ? ChangedFileName : fileUploadDownloadable.FileName;

            using (var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(new AmazonS3Client(apiId, keyName, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)))
            {
                var bucketName = Globals.configSettings.AmazonS3ApiBucketName;                    
                var inputStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
                var key = "images/downloads/" + fileName;                    

                fileTransferUtility.Upload(inputStream, bucketName, key);
            }
```